# Including conditional files with Yii 2's registerJsFile method

Tags: php, yii, conditional-statements, yii2

Using `Yii 2` and there doesn't appear to be any documentation on how to include script files that should be contained within `conditional statements`.

Normally you would include a script such as:

```
$this->registerJsFile($base_url . '/js/script.js', array('position' => $this::POS_HEAD), 'my-script');
```

But what do you do if the scripts need to go within conditional statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Yii2` supports conditional comments in a way like below:

```
$this->registerJsFile('path/to/file.js', ['condition'=>'lt IE 9']);
```

Above code will generate below code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="path/to/file.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

As `Yii2`'s official document says:

> **condition**: specifies the conditional comments for IE, e.g., lt IE 9. When this is specified, the generated link tag will be enclosed within the conditional comments. This is mainly useful for supporting old versions of IE browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot - do you have a link for that page handy where that quote came from?

Comment: @Brett You're welcome dear, Here you are : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#jsFile()-detail